# Integrals of the form $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^p dx$

Tags: integration, rational-functions

Find $$\int{x^{13/2}(1+x^{5/2})^{1/2}}dx$$

---

### My attempt:

Usually when I face the form $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^p dx$, I would factor out $x^n$ and proceed.

---

**Example:**

$$I=\int{x^{-11}(1+x^4)^{-1/2}}dx$$

$$I=\int{x^{-13}(1+\frac{1}{x^4})^{-1/2}dx}$$

Let $t=1+\frac{1}{x^4} \implies dt=\frac{-4}{x^5}dx$

$$I=\int{\frac{-1}{4}\frac{(t-1)^2}{\sqrt t}}dt$$

which is now very easy to evaluate.

---

Coming back to the **original** problem,

$$I=\int{x^{13/2}(1+x^{5/2})^{1/2}}dx$$
Proceeding in the *usual* way,

$$I=\int{x^{31/4}(1+\frac{1}{x^{5/2}})^{1/2}}dx$$

Setting $t=1+\frac{1}{x^{5/2}} \implies dt=\frac{-5}{2x^{7/2}}dx$

$$I=\int{\frac{-2}{5}x^{45/4}\sqrt t}dt$$

$$I=\int{\frac{-2}{5}\frac{\sqrt t}{(t-1)^{9/2}}}dt$$

which is disappointing, since it doesn't yield anything.

---

### Questions:

**1)** Why did the usual method not work here? Does it not work for some specific cases? If yes, when?

**2)** How can the integral be solved?

**3)** Is there any general approach for solving $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^p dx $ ?

Comment: See my answer to [Integrate $(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/715715/13130), which cites (with link provided) where in Hardy's book **The Integration of Functions of a Single Variable** this type of integral is discussed.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The reference is really helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

For integrals known as [Differential binomial](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential_binomial)
$$\int x^m(a+bx^n)^p dx$$
where $m,n,p$ are rational numbers are following methods:

1. p whole integer. Take $x=z^N$ where $N$ common denominator of $m,n$.
2. $\frac{m+1}{n}$ whole integer. Then we use $a+x^{n}b=z^N$, where $N$ is denominator of $p$.
3. $\frac{m+1}{n}+p$ whole integer. Then we use $ax^{-n}+b=z^N$, where $N$ is denominator of $p$.

In all other cases, the integral of a differential binomial cannot be expressed by elementary functions (P.L. Chebyshev, 1853).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you provide some intuition on why/how this works? I would also like the answer to address the flaw in my method

Comment: @DatBoi.Your case seems is 2nd. $\frac{\frac{13}{2}+1}{\frac{5}{2}}=3$. No? Also added last line for for completeness of answer.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Write, please, if/when some more questions will arise.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you meant by that.

Comment: ask again when needed - nothing more.

Comment: Sure. Very kind of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not,

$$ x^{ \frac52} = t$$
Then,

$$ x^{ \frac32} dx= \frac{2}{5} dt$$

Our integral was:

$$\int{x^{13/2}(1+x^{5/2})^{1/2}}dx$$

It becomes:

$$ \int t^2 ( 1 + t)^{\frac12} \frac{2dt}{5}$$

Now, integrate by parts:

$$ \frac{2}{3} [ (1+t)^{\frac32} t^2 -  \int (2t) (1+t)^{\frac32} dt]$$

And one more integration by part finishes the job.