# Definite Integral of a cube root

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, roots

I'm having trouble with this integral, I tried different t substition, u substition, integration by parts, but it just complicates it and I get nowhere.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}dx$$

Comment: Precisely which substitutions did you try? It's better if you're more specific about what you've tried, so we can better help you.

Comment: There is no elementary antiderivative according to Wolfram Alpha, so you're going to have to apply some advanced trick that only works for definite integrals.

Comment: My best guess at the moment for something approaching an answer would be a hyperbolic trig sub. Let $x = \sinh(u)$. Then $x^2+1 = \sin^2(u) + 1 = \cosh^2(u)$ and $dx = \cosh(u) \, du$, so

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x^2+1} \, dx = \int_0^{\sinh(1)} \cosh^{5/3}(u) \, du$$

An approximation could be made using the definition of $\cosh(x)$ in terms of $e^x$ and binomial series or other such items.

Comment: [Another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712170/integrate-x21-frac13?noredirect=1) on it being nonelementary, and a series solution.

Comment: Mathematica gives it as HypergeometricFunction2F1$[-1/6,1/2,4/2,-1]$